# How to connect gmail account through VC#

Tags: c#, google-api

I want to write a simple program which has a username and password field when I click the button it should display a message box saying "Successful login" and connect with my gmail account.

The code should use Http header..

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "connect with my gmail account"? What are you trying to do after completing the login?

Comment: I mean I just want to display a login successful message..after entering my details and clicking the button....

Answer (score 2):

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSharpGmail

Comment: Thanks but..I mean I just want to display a login successful message..after entering my details and clicking the button....

Answer (score 0):

You should be clearer about what you want - the title says

> How to connect gmail account through VC#

For that, the answer given by FractalizeR is correct

If all you want is to show a message than that's another story, try:

```
MessageBox.Show("MessageTextHere", "CaptionTextHere")
```

Or any of it's [many variants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)